# Magento2.4.2 layout

Tags: layout, magento2.4.2

Is there any difference between the two layouts

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "Custom Design Update" section allows you to schedule a design change and is only available in Adobe Commerce (previously Magento Commerce/Enterprise/EE edition/whatever you want to call it).

The "Design" section only allows you to make the change manually and cannot be scheduled.

Comment: Thank you very much